# How to add input into a website that is retrieved by Shell script so that the out can be printed out?

Tags: shell

I have the following Shell script below which can download the website into a variable.  This is as far as I have got.  What I would like to do is add input into this website (which accepts an IP address, and outputs ones location) from the console when I execute a Shell script with an argument(IP address) so that it can output the geographical location of the IP address.  Please can anyone help.

```
 #! /bin/bash

 read input
 content=$(wget http://freegeoip.net -q )
 echo $content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the following as a file called `getgeo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
location=$(curl -s http://freegeoip.net/csv/$1)
echo $location
```

Then use it like this:

```
chmod +x getgeo
./getgeo 141.20.1.33
"141.20.1.33","DE","Germany","16","Berlin","Berlin","","52.5167","13.4000","",""
```

Or, if you just want the 5th and 3rd field and no quotes, do this:

```
./getgeo 141.20.1.33 | tr -d '"' | awk -F, '{print $5,$3}'
Berlin Germany
```

Or, you can do the trimming inside the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
location=$(curl -s http://freegeoip.net/csv/$1)
echo $location | tr -d '"' | awk -F, '{print $5,$3}'
```

If you prefer parsing XML or JSON, you can change the `/csv/` to `/XML/` or `/JSON/` and you will get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response> <Ip>92.238.99.46</Ip> <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode> <CountryName>United Kingdom</CountryName> <RegionCode>E6</RegionCode> <RegionName>Gloucestershire</RegionName> <City>Gloucester</City> <ZipCode>GL3</ZipCode> <Latitude>51.8456</Latitude> <Longitude>-2.1575</Longitude> <MetroCode></MetroCode> <AreaCode></AreaCode> </Response>
```

or JSON

```
{"ip":"141.20.1.33","country_code":"DE","country_name":"Germany","region_code":"16","region_name":"Berlin","city":"Berlin","zipcode":"","latitude":52.5167,"longitude":13.4,"metro_code":"","areacode":""}
```

**Notes:**

The command `tr -d '"'` removes all double quotes from whatever it receives as input:

The `-F,` switch to `awk` says to uses the comma as the field separator.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **curl** - go ahead and refer to the documentation in the following site:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#GET

> The simplest and most common request/operation made using HTTP is to get a URL. The URL could itself refer to a web page, an image or a file. The client issues a GET request to the server and receives the document it asked for. If you issue the command line
>
> ```
> curl http://curl.haxx.se
> ```
>
> you get a web page returned in your terminal window. The entire HTML document that that URL holds.

Therefore, you can achieve what you want by redirecting the output of **curl freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname}** to a file, and then grep the info you want from it.